# Implement Laravel API Routes with versioning

Tags: laravel, api, rest, routes, laravel-8

I want to make an API for my project

i can make something like:

```
/api/something
```

basically adding routes in `/routes/api.php`

But i want to make versioning like:

```
/api/v1/something
```

So i want to know how to group all api routes for v1, v2 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Write all your route inside a prefix named v1:

```
Route::group(["prefix" => "v1"], function () {
//Write your routes here
});
```